# Multiple select in Vim

Tags: vim, sublimetext2

Can I do multiple select same words in `Vim` as that was in `Sublime text 2` with command `ctrl+D` and then edit selected words?

Comment: how do you do that in vim? :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yep! Check this out: [vim-multiple-cursors](https://github.com/terryma/vim-multiple-cursors)

Answer (score 3):

No you can't but [someone is working on it](http://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/10xn0m/markmultiple_for_vim_didnt_exist_so_ive_created_it/).